# htaccess: its been overwrite wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, vesta

I have a virtualhost in vestacp for a domain with wordpress. I need it to add more memory and filesize limits. First i created php.ini and php5.ini in  wp-admin but it didnt work. So I added this to my .htaccess file located in /home/nextop/web/domain.com/public_html/.htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_time 180
```

then i restart apache

```
httpd stop
httpd start
```

and everything works. But after a few days my .htaccess file is empty.

How can I have that configuration permanent?

Comment: The file is empty? Someone else is overwriting your file?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress

Comment: no on has access

Comment: Then you must be overwriting the file yourself. There is nothing that just replaces or overwrites the file magically.